# Process.Start() significantly slower than executing in console

Tags: c#, .net

I have performance problems executing an .exe using `Process.Start()`. The execution takes roughly 5 times longer from .NET then it does from console. What can cause this? Here is a test program:

```
  public static void Main(string[] argv)
  {       
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExePath, Args);
        Process ps = new Process {StartInfo = psi};
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ps.Start();
        ps.WaitForExit();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(i+" Elapsed time: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
  }
```

The result is this:

```
 0 Elapsed time 4310ms.
 1 Elapsed time 4330ms.
 2 Elapsed time 4280ms.
 ...
```

Running it in a cmd window returns almost immediately (sub 1 second execution). Tried timing it in the console using

```
> powershell Measure-Command { cmd /c start /wait %EXE% %ARGS% }
```

Which shows around 750ms for the execution, which is a good 5-6 times faster. Not sure I did that right, but 750ms feels like a likely execution time.

At first I was reading std out and thought it was related to this, see e.g. [Process takes longer to finish than in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638304/process-takes-longer-to-finish-than-in-cmd) and similar questions. Obviously in the simple test program I'm not reading any output now, just executing.

Possible causes I have alreay ruled out that cause no difference in exec time:

- Debugger/no debugger
- Debug/Release build of .NET host process
- Working directory
- Platform of host .NET process Any/x86/x64 (exe is native x64)
- UseShellExecute true/false

What I do know about the executable (It's the rust statement completion tool 'racer' https://github.com/phildawes/racer) is that it will go off and open lots of files. Could that matter when coming from the .NET host, e.g. wrt. security, that causes the slowdown? What else could cause the huge performance difference?

Comment: You are timing a lot more than just starting the process.

Comment: @leppie what would that be? I don't see a lot more there.

Comment: @usr, creation of both the start info and the process instances. Create both upfront, the start timing just before calling `procinstance.Start()`

Comment: I cannot image creating these two object taking multiple seconds. More like Microseconds.

Comment: It takes some time for your powershell window to "get ready" as well(before you can type in it). Are you considering this in your "powershell window" timing? Because it's included in your "process timing".

Comment: The powershell command when run from cmd doesn't create a new window. Besides, if we timed more in the console the numbers would be even worse. Apart from moving the ProcessStartInfo construction  outside of the stopwatch (makes no difference), I don't see how I could time any less here. The Start() call creates the process, not sure I can create a process instance without starting?

Comment: Edited to just time from Start() to WaitForExit(). The timings are the same.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: You are still timing the creation of the `Process` instance that is internal to `Process.Start()`.

Comment: That would be the answer to my question, if there was any reason at all that creating the process (object) would take 3 seconds+. The difference to creating that outside the sw is insignificant, as expected. Editing the code example.

Comment: You could try using `procmon` from sysinternals.com to see what is being done differently from the process perspective..

Comment: @AndersForsgren: Sorry, I thought you solved it.

Comment: It's just a hunch, but does your measurement change if you sleep for a few seconds before starting the StopWatch and calling `ps.Start()` ?

Comment: @helb, that makes no difference

Comment: @AndersForsgren: Using `new ProcessStartInfo(ExePath, Args) { CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false };` is the best I can get. When executing `where where`, it takes 100ms on average.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: You can also check `ps.UserProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds` to see the actual time.

Comment: @PabloMontilla running procmon I can see that the .NET exe takes around 0.4seconds before launching the native exe, which then generates 29k events, taking 3 seconds longer in total when run from .NET than from console. The events (reg key reads, file opens..) each seem to take around 20% longer when run from .NET, and there is no point where it seems to pause or any obvious issues. So: the same amount of events (29k) seem arrive evenly from beginning to end in both cases, simply at a lower frequency, and taking slightly more time each when run from .NET.

Comment: It makes no sense that system functions are slower when run from .NET...maybe the .NET process is using virtualized registry access? What happens if you compare side by side one of the accesses that takes longer on the .NET side vs the one on the native side?

Comment: @PabloMontilla one difference I can spot is that the console execution seems to load some files from prefetch, whereas .NET does not. There is nothing else that sticks out as unusual. The sum time of the 29k events is 0.8sec vs 1.0sec, so the difference in event duration only accounts for part of the time.

Comment: I can check the two logs if you post them, maybe with fresh eyes we can spot something you didn't?

Comment: @PabloMontilla Thanks. I just posted it here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22904108/Stackoverflow/ProcessMystery.zip 
Note that the logs hold only the execution of the native exe, i.e. the .NET process bits first/last have been cut.

Comment: Sorry, can you use the procmon format for the files? (.PML) I want to see the exact calls! =)

Comment: I've noticed you are running different `racer.exe` files (differing in size also). Maybe it's got something to do with that?

Comment: Ouch, you nailed it! It was slightly different revisions of the binary with the huge perf difference. What a facepalm. I wish you had an answer I could accept to at least credit you the points. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in running time in this case was due to different versions of the executed (`racer.exe`) file, and had nothing to do with the fact that one was being executed from a .NET process and the other from the command line.

There shouldn't be a difference when running an executable from .NET as it is simply using system calls to execute the program.

Comment: Exactly this. Any perf differences should only be because of how the output streams are read (buffering/blocking)

Comment: Actually surprised i am also running in to this issue. Basically doing a process.start and kick off exiftool. Same version running inside takes longer to update one file vs the same takes a second in cmd. There has to be some bug here. I can provide more if no if needed

Answer (score 2):

```
    ps.WaitForExit();
```

That's the statement that makes the difference.  Your cmd.exe command doesn't wait for the process to terminate.  Either remove WaitForExit() or use "cmd /c start /wait %EXE% %ARGS%" to compare apples to oranges.

Or in other words, you didn't measure how long it took to start a process, you measured how long the process was running.

Comment: Thanks, this makes only a tiny difference. It still returns in < 1 second. Will update the question so there is no confusion.

Comment: Well, does PowerShell actually wait itself?  Probably not, get the "fast" version by removing the WaitForExit() statement.  And the Thread.Sleep(), that's pointless.

Comment: What I really want to do is get the time until it has completed, i.e. (it writes some output to stdout and then exits). If I do it "by eye" at the console I can at least see how long it takes until it writes the stdout and returns me to the console, it's around 1sec for the native and >4sec for the above .NET wrapper. Looking in procmon for the latter, I can see that the actual execution of the native (timestamps of its events) exe takes more than 3 secs when called from .NET. If I don't have WaitForExit() it will report some insignificant time, then wait 4 sec and write the stdout.

Comment: That has something to do with the program you start.  I can't make any decent guess without knowing anything about it, but many programs require the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property to be set to the same directory that contains the .exe to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I run in the same environment, at least wrt. working dir and environment variables :(

Comment: You are entirely correct: the two binaries timed weren't exactly the same (in some way I don't yet understand but will try to figure out). Imagine, going through all that trouble fixing the equal environment, then benchmarking completely separate programs. I hate programming. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

A very late comment, but today 2023, it seems to be still the case. Running on a nvidia jetson, with 4GB memory the difference is huge, when ran from C# it is 3 times slower....

I already ran some platform functions in python, which tell me how much memory and such I have.
Here a code snippet.

I don 't have time for now to solve the issue getting the code right performing is a huge challenge, as most examples, even codegpt sucks at generating the best code for a ssim which has decent performance and accurateness.

Maybe somebody sees this remark and has the golden bullet to solve the question.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new(_pathHelper.PythonPath.Value, arguments)
    {
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    using var proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo)!;
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

    proc.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) => streamStdOutWriter.WriteIfNotNull(e.Data);
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) => errors.AddIfNotNull(e.Data);

    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{_pathHelper.PythonPath.Value} {arguments}");
        await proc.WaitForExitAsync(two.Token);
```