# Executing a bash script takes much more time when using Process.Start than when using regular console

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

First time poster, over 10 years reader :)

The issue:
I made a simple bash script:

```
#/bin/bash
date >> test.db
tac /Users/user/Desktop/catalina.out.2022-06-17-06H30M | grep [Info] | grep -m 1000 "Duration: " >> test.txt
date >> test.db
```

When I run this code using my terminal, it takes less than 2 seconds to execute.
When I run the same script using my .NET application, it takes about 30 seconds to execute.

Verry similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168762/process-start-significantly-slower-than-executing-in-console) problem.

Here is my c# code:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        Process myProc = new Process();
        myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "/opt/homebrew/bin/bash";
        myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-c \"/Users/user/Desktop/test.sh \"";
        myProc.Start();
        this.result = await  myProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        myProc.WaitForExit();


        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration = end - start;
        this.duration = duration.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

There is no using statement now, because code is being debugged :)
I'm using M1 macbook (ARM), have not treid code on other platforms (targeting Linux x64).

I've tried most other answers with simmilar problems. More often than not, problem other people had was calling diferent .exe or something similar.

**EDIT**
After deploying app on Linux, it works instantly. The same code is painfully slow on my Mac.  I guess it has something to do with console buffer maybe?

Comment: You could try adding more measurements to narrow down the problem - grab the timestamps between `Start()` and `ReadToEndAsync()` and again before calling `WaitForExit()`

Comment: Thank you for your time.
I already tried that.
When debugging, I've noticed that most of the time is spent on waiting for: ReadToEndAsync().
If I comment that line out, most of time is spent waiting for: WaitForExit().
In both cases, it takes 30 seconds to execute. 
Also, I can see BASH process in Activity manager and using TOP command, but it seems not to be consuming any CPU or DISK activity. After about 30 seconds BASH process exits and my code continues execution..
If I were on windows, I could use a process monitor or some similar tool.

Comment: Also, if i comment  ReadToEndAsync(), 30 sec wait is now on WaitForExit()
If I comment WaitForExit(), 30 second wait is now on ReadToEndAsync().
If i leave them both be, 30 seconds wait is on ReadToEndAsync(), and WaitForExit() completes instantly.

Comment: What is the current directory from which you run (1) the script in the console and (2) the .NET application? Note that you are not specifying the target directory in `date >> test.db`, nor in `tac ... >> test.txt`, so it creates these files in whichever directory you're in. If you're running the .NET application from some place where you don't have write access, or from some place where writing is very slow (e.g. a directory mounted on a mobile phone's memory), then that would account for the long time it takes to run the subprocess.

Comment: Thank you for your time Klitos.
I've thought about that. Both locations are on my internal SSD. In my /Users/User directory.
One is ./Desktop, other is ./Repos./bin./debug...
Just to be sure, I've added this line:
myProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "/Users/user/Desktop";
Same results. There is no network traffic, slow disk or anything like that involved, only fast SSD.

Comment: What do the lines in test.db tell you? Are the last 2 lines 30 seconds apart, or is there a long delay between the .NET application's `DateTime start` value and the start time of the bash process, or a long delay between the end time of the bash process and the end time of the .NET application?

Comment: When I start the script using the console, they are 1 second apart. When I start using my .NET app, they are 30 seconds apart.
There is no delay between DateTIme start value, and the start time of the bash process, nor between end value and the exiting bash process.

Bash script just seems to be executing longer in that case. I even thought about adding the current DateTime stamp to every line outputted by TAC command.

Comment: By the way, I've just noticed `grep [Info]` is looking for any line containing any of the characters I, n, f, or o (since grep uses regular expressions). That's not what you intended to search for. Not relevant to the question though.

Comment: Check the value of your PATH in each case (`echo $PATH >> path.txt`). Perhaps you're using a different version of `tac` or `grep` in each case due to the PATH being different.

Comment: You are right, i will make it right. Also, please  see the relevant edit on the question, I think I pinpointed the problem.
I've checked path, its the same binary in both cases....